# Find/Replace regex to rearrange text in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have certain data that I want to rearrange (it's all on the same line) I have tried multiple approaches but I can't get it to work.

Here is an example of the text:

```
DATA1="8DE" DATA2="322" DATA3="20" DATA4="19.99" DATA5="0.01"
DATA1="FE4" DATA2="222" DATA4="400" DATA3="400" DATA5="0.00"
DATA1="CE3" DATA2="444" DATA4="60" DATA5="0.00" DATA3="60"
DATA1="MME" DATA3="20" DATA4="20" DATA5="0.00"
DATA2="667" DATA4="30" DATA3="30" DATA5="0.00" DATA1="MH4"
```

This should be the output:

```
8DE     322     20      19.99   0.01
FE4     222     400     400     0.00
CE3     444     60      60      0.00
MME             20      20      0.00
MH4     667     30      30      0.00
```

I have tried the following but to no avail:

FIND: `DATA1=\"(.*?)\"|DATA2=\"(.*?)\"|DATA3=\"(.*?)\"|DATA4=\"(.*?)\"|DATA5=\"(.*?)\"`

REPLACE: `\1  \2  \3  \4  \5`

and

FIND: `DATA1=\"(?<d1>.*?)\"|DATA2=\"(?<d2>.*?)\"|DATA3=\"(?<d3>.*?)\"|DATA4=\"(?<d4>.*?)\"|DATA5=\"(?<d5>.*?)\"`

REPLACE: `$+{d1} $+{d2} $+{d3} $+{d4} $+{d5}`

I would be happy if someone can help or direct me to the right answer (and sorry for any misunderstanding as english is not my first languaje)

Comment: Why are the `MME` and `MH4` rows flipped?

Comment: The data follows the same pattern but sometimes is arranged differently, thats why I'm trying to rearrange the data thru REGEX

Comment: Can the result be MME, then MH4? The way you currently have it is impossible with regex alone.

Comment: Oh! I now see what you mean, I edited the text so the rows are in correct order.

Yes, you were right, the rows maintain their order.
1..
2..
3..
and so...

Comment: The vertical bars (`|`) in your regexes denote alternation, but not in the way you at hoping for. See the words about *"optional lookaheads"* in the answer by @ctwheels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The regex

```
^(?=.*\bDATA1="([^"]+)"\h*)?(?=.*\bDATA2="([^"]+)"\h*)?(?=.*\bDATA3="([^"]+)"\h*)?(?=.*\bDATA4="([^"]+)"\h*)?(?=.*\bDATA5="([^"]+)"\h*)?.*
```

This regex works by using optional lookaheads to locate `DATAx` (where `x` is the number) and capturing the value inside the `"` into a capture group, then matching the whole line (in order to replace it).

### The replacement

```
$1\t\t$2\t\t$3\t\t$4\t\t$5
```

This replacement just references the capture groups and adds tab characters between them while reordering them in the order of `DATA [1,2,3,4,5]`.

### The result

```
8DE     322     20      19.99       0.01
FE4     222     400     400     0.00
CE3     444     60      60      0.00
MME             20      20      0.00
MH4     667     30      30      0.00
```

---

#### See it working

[See the regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/jy8Hbm/2)